# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error when running as a java application

Tags: sslexception

I am using RAD8.0.4, Websphere Application Server v8.0 JRE, Java version 1.8.0_351.

I would appreciate if anyone can provide the resolution for this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.p.a(p.java:25)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.p.a(p.java:23)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.b(SSLSocketImpl.java:617)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:28)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:801)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:303)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:364)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:188)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:3)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:11)
    at gov.illinois.fw.management.util.CmsTokenGenerationOne.main(CmsTokenGenerationOne.java:26)
```

I am expecting to get the Restful token back from the Restful token service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post to include a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can debug your code and better provide solutions.